# Flipclock initial value of 939,511,314?

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I call Jquery FlipClock with the following parameters.  The first number I see is 939,511,314.  But after that, it works perfectly.  Obviously this is not really causing a huge problem, but it's very odd.  I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this?

```
clock = new FlipClock($(selector), 40620004, {
  clockFace: "Counter",
  autoStart: true,
  minimumDigits: 9
});
setTimeout(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    clock.increment(22);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Could you add a demo of the problem? (A link to your site, a JSfiddle, a CodePen, or a snippet?)

Comment: what is the use of 40620004 here?

Comment: Here is my test site.  It's a work in progress, it could be up and down.
http://2018.boomerangdm.com

The 40,620,004 is a dollar amount.